# How insert csv into mysql with rails in join table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models Items Gosts and Item_Gosts
item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_gosts
    has_many :gosts, through: :item_gosts
end
```

item_gost.rb

```
   class ItemGost < ActiveRecord::Base
          belongs_to :item
          belongs_to :gost
        end
```

gost.rb

```
class Gost < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_gosts
    has_many :items, through: :item_gosts
end
```

Now i need import csv file into ItemGost table

ItemGost it's join table and have this structure
| id | item_id | gost_id |

and i have csv file with item_id and collection from Gost.name it have this structure

```
item_id,gosts_names
1,8734; 14-162-184-2150; 8758
2,8734; 14-161-184-2000; 8732
```

How i can do import with csv file?

Gost.rb

```
def self.import(file)
      CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        item = Item.find_by_id(row["item_id"])
        gosts = Gost.find_or_create_by(name: row["gosts_names"].split(;))
        ?????
        item.save!
      end
    end
```

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with?  From your code it looks like you're almost there.  Though this `gosts = Gost.find_or_create_by(name: row["gosts_names"].split(;))` won't work.  Are you just trying to assign the gosts to the items?

Comment: Yep, I just create string in ItemGost table, where item_id = item_id in csv and gost_id = gosts_names split by ;

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you can do it through the association methods rails provides:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    item = Item.find_by_id(row["item_id"])
    gosts = []
    row["gosts_names"].split(;).each do |gost_name|
      gosts << Gost.find_or_create_by(name: gost_name)
    end
    item.gosts = gosts 
    item.save!
  end
end
```